# How to retrieve the result of javascript function in the serverside?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have javascript function return `array` like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function looping() {
            var column_num = 1;
            var array = [];
            $("#columns ul").not("#column1").each(function() {

                var ulId = $(this).attr("id");
                var ulClass = $(this).attr("class");

                if (ulId != undefined && ulClass != undefined) {
                    var order = -1;
                    column_num++;
                    $("li", $(this)).each(function() {

                        var liId = $(this).attr("id");
                        var liClass = $(this).attr("class");
                        if (liId != undefined && liClass != undefined) {
                            order++;

                            var result = liId + "|" + liClass + "|" + column_num + "|" + order;

                            array.push(result);

                            //alert(array[0]);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return array;
        }

    </script>
```

---

How can I retrieve the result in another array in my code behind `.cs` in button click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the array in a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="hidfld" id="hidfld" />` inside your form.

```
document.getElementById("hidfld").value = array;
```

On the serverside, use the hidden field's name to retrieve the array

Comment: How to store array in hidden field ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("hidfld").value = array;`

Comment: hmmmm, i wanna to execute this function in specific event . this will return old version

Comment: I mean ,  i need this function to execute in the event handler of exit button , because the function will return different result during this period.

Comment: just i call my function in `OnClientClick="looping();"` , and storing in the hidden field.thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

The only way i see is send result using [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [GET](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) AJAX request.

```
 $.get("/server/page.aspx", {  looping: looping() });
```

On ServerSide do:

```
 var array = Request.Params["looping"];
```